# Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable

Tags: javascript

My variable is not a constant and I still get an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable." Any idea why?

snake.js

```
export let SNAKE_SPEED = 3;
```

food.js

```
import { snakeBody, SNAKE_SPEED } from "./snake.js";

export function update() {

  let head = snakeBody[0];
  if (head.x == food.x && head.y == food.y) {
    food.x = Math.round(Math.random() * 21);
    food.y = Math.round(Math.random() * 21);
    SNAKE_SPEED++;
  }

}
```

The variable in question being SNAKE_SPEED.

Answer (score 6):

Identifiers imported from other modules cannot be reassigned. To achieve something like this, you can have the other module export a function that changes it, eg:

```
export let SNAKE_SPEED = 3;
export const changeSnakeSpeed = newSpeed => SNAKE_SPEED = newSpeed;
```

```
import { snakeBody, SNAKE_SPEED, changeSnakeSpeed } from "./snake.js";
```

and then call `changeSnakeSpeed(SNAKE_SPEED + 1)`, and `SNAKE_SPEED` will have changed.

Or do something like

```
export const incrementSnakeSpeed = () => SNAKE_SPEED++;
```

```
incrementSnakeSpeed();
```

Or put the often-changeable variables into a single object that can be mutated (or reassigned and retrieved again, if you prefer immutability).

Comment: Wow. That totally makes sense now. So it's pretty much like creating a setter, right?

Comment: Sure, though it's a of a smelly issue to be having IMO - identifiers (imported from other modules) seemingly changing on their own is quite unintuitive. You might consider a getter too. `export const getSnakeSpeed = () => SNAKE_SPEED`

Comment: Everything works like a charm now. Thanks!